# Read data from Sqlite in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to read data from sqlite in Objective-C, but the result is QuestionNumber and TotalRate both is 0, can not read value from sqlite. Please helper how should I change my code?

```
-(void)readSqlite{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Questiondata.db"];
    NSLog(@"filePath,%@",filePath);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSLog(@"database is exist.");
        NSMutableArray *retArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        const char *dbpath = [filePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSLog(@"THIS IS OK");
            const char *insert_stmt = "SELECT QuestionNumber, TotalRate FROM Questions WHERE QuestionNumber = 2";
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                NSLog(@"SQLITE_OK");
                int QuestionNumberx = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                int TotalRate = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);

                NSLog(@"QuestionNumberx %d",QuestionNumberx );
                NSLog(@"TotalRate %d",TotalRate );

                [retArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:QuestionNumberx]];
                [retArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TotalRate]];

                NSLog(@"%s db err '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB), sqlite3_errcode(_contactDB));

                NSLog(@"retArray %@",retArray );

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"database is not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy thanks. I am new and self learning. I have to learn a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually execute the query with `sqlite3_step`. You also never close the database.

The following assumes you will only get a single record back from your query:

```
-(void)readSqlite{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Questiondata.db"];
    NSLog(@"filePath,%@",filePath);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSLog(@"database is exist.");
        NSMutableArray *retArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        const char *dbpath = [filePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSLog(@"THIS IS OK");
            const char *insert_stmt = "SELECT QuestionNumber, TotalRate FROM Questions WHERE QuestionNumber = 2";
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                NSLog(@"SQLITE_OK");
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    int QuestionNumberx = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                    int TotalRate = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);

                    NSLog(@"QuestionNumberx %d",QuestionNumberx );
                    NSLog(@"TotalRate %d",TotalRate );

                    [retArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:QuestionNumberx]];
                    [retArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TotalRate]];

                    NSLog(@"retArray %@",retArray );
                }

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Unable to prepare statement: %s db err '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB), sqlite3_errcode(_contactDB));
            }

            sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable top open database.");
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"database is not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a typo on my part. Change `insert_stmt` to `statement`.

Comment: I have more question. How to change `int TotalRate = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1); `If the TotalRante is string. and how tho change `insert_stmt = "SELECT QuestionNumber, TotalRate FROM Questions WHERE QuestionNumber = 2";` if the 2 determined by variable, for example 2 is IDNumber.

Comment: Do some research on `sqlite3_column_text` and binding variables to a query.

Comment: `int QuestionNumberx = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);`  // for int,   `float AverageRate =sqlite3_column_double(statement, 2);`//for float,     `const unsigned char *questions = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7);`//for text